# What can be said about something that one has to get used to in order to start using it at its best?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Here's a question (a part of a made-up conversation):

> "What unusually shaped guitar you were playing on at the concert! Did
>   it take you long to get used to it?"

**My question:**

Would it be idiomatic to use "guitar" as the subject, answering:

> A new guitar always takes some time getting used to.

Or

> A new guitar always takes some time to be gotten used to.

Or

In the phrase "to get used to something", should that something *always* be the object?

> It always takes (one) some time to get used to playing
>   (on) a new guitar.

What another alternative is there for me, if there is one, regarding the idea I'd wish to express using the above idiom?

Comment: The word "adapt" could be a one-word substitution for the phrase. 1) *Adapting to any guitar takes a bit of time.* 2) *A new guitar always involves some adaption time.*

Comment: You're making it too complicated.  "A new guitar always takes time **to get used to**" is fine.

Comment: *A new guitar takes some getting used to.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite acceptable to use guitar, and you can use either the -ing or a to-infinitive (I prefer the infinitive)

> A new guitar takes some time (to get/getting) used to.

You can also use "it" (as a "weather it")

> It takes some time to get used to a new guitar.

The passive form "be got/gotten used to" seems ugly, I wouldn't use it, but it is grammatically correct too

For example in a site about [purchasing a mattress](https://www.cgmattress.com/bed-in-a-box) they say "A new mattress takes time to get used to, so we recommend spending at least 30 nights sleeping on your mattress..." So this structure is used by native speakers.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. So "this gadget is quite easy to get used to" also works, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the phrase "break [something] in" or "break in "

It means to use something until it is comfortable. The changes could occur in the object itself, or the user.

Ex.
I just bought these new leather shoes. It will take me a few months to break them in. (Perhaps the shoes will become supple and adjust to their owners feet after months of use)

I'm going to break in my new mouse in this AI game before I head to a PvP game. (The mouse itself likely does not undergo any changes but the user will become accustomed to using it)

Of course you can use guitar:

It always takes time to break a new guitar in.

Answer (score 0):

*to get used to* is being used as a *verb*, and verbs act on *objects*.

*get* is an overused word in the English language, and in the case of *get used to* it takes the place of far more descriptive words, such as *acclimate*, *accustom*, *acquaint*, *adapt*, or *adjust*.  For example:

> A new guitar always takes some time to adapt to.
>
> A new guitar always takes some time to adjust to.

You *adapt* to *something* and you *adjust* to *something*, so you *get used* to *something*.  That *something* is always the *object*, because *adapt*, *adjust*, and *to get used to* are the *verbs*.

In spoken English, the immediate focus of the conversation usually determines how the sentence is constructed.  So if the focus is the *guitar*, it comes first in the sentence:

> A new guitar always takes some time to get used to.

If the focus is more on the *person*, the person comes first:

> *He* always takes some time to get used to a new guitar.
>
> *Sally* always takes some time to get used to a new guitar.

If the focus is on the *time it takes*:

> It always takes some time to get used to a new guitar.

Regardless of the structure, the *guitar* is the object because it is being *adapted to*, *adjusted to*, or *gotten used to*.